# Oracle SQL query to exclue a set of records based on values

Tags: sql, oracle

My post title might be awkward, but let me try to explain what I am trying to achieve with an oracle sql query.

My table is as below.

Requirement is, when the seqNo is **shared** by "apple", then I **Do Not** want the record to be selected.

Only if Apple alone is having a sequence number(Not shared by any other Category), only then select the record, as shown in the below table.

Any help is highly appreciated.

I tried to partion based on seqNo, and ranking it on category, but since the category is string, I could not achieve it.

```
|SeqNo   |   Category|
|------ |---------|
|1    |   Banana|
|3    |   Apple ---> *do not select as sequence number is shared*|
|3    |   Orange ---> *do not select as sequence number is shared*|
|4    |   Mango|
|4    |   Banana|
|7    |   Orange---> *do not select as sequence number is shared*|
|7    |   Apple---> *do not select as sequence number is shared*|
|7    |   Mango---> *do not select as sequence number is shared*|
|9    |   Apple-->**Only Select this**|
|11   |   Banana|
|13   |   Mango|
|14   |   Apple-->**Only Select this**|
|18   |   Apple-->**Only Select this**|
|42   |   Mango|
```

Comment: What if there are two apples?

Comment: Yes, both need to be selected. Eg. if  21-> apple and 21 -> apple would be a duplicate record. so either way should be fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Schema:

```
 create table mytable (SeqNo int,   Category varchar(505));
 insert into mytable values(1    ,'Banana');
 insert into mytable values(3    ,'Apple');
 insert into mytable values(3    ,'Orange');
 insert into mytable values(4    ,'Mango');
 insert into mytable values(4    ,'Banana');
 insert into mytable values(7    ,'Orange');
 insert into mytable values(7    ,'Apple');
 insert into mytable values(7    ,'Mango');
 insert into mytable values(9    ,'Apple');
 insert into mytable values(11   ,'Banana');
 insert into mytable values(13   ,'Mango');
 insert into mytable values(14   ,'Apple');
 insert into mytable values(18   ,'Apple');
 insert into mytable values(42   ,'Mango');
```

Query#1 (to find rows for seqno with single record and which is 'Apple')

```
  with cte as ( select seqno,category,count(*)over(partition by seqno ) cnt from mytable )
  select * from cte where cnt=1 and trim(category)='Apple'
```

Output:

| seqno | category | cnt |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 9 | Apple | 1 |
| 14 | Apple | 1 |
| 18 | Apple | 1 |

Query#2 (to remove the rows which have multiple rows for a sequence number and one have category 'Apple')

```
     with cte as 
     (
         select seqno,category,count(*)over(partition by seqno ) cnt from mytable
     )
     select * from mytable 
     where not exists
                    (
                     select * from cte where cnt=2 and trim(Category)='Apple' and 
                     mytable.seqno=cte.seqno
                    );
```

Output:

| SeqNo | Category |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | Banana |
| 4 | Mango |
| 4 | Banana |
| 9 | Apple |
| 11 | Banana |
| 13 | Mango |
| 14 | Apple |
| 18 | Apple |
| 42 | Mango |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=b973fa010ce26352792498c042563346)*

Comment: If any of the answer helped to solve the problem please accept that by clicking green check.

Comment: JAK, Thank you very much. I was able to tweek your query a little bit and get the needed response.                                                                                                          
with cte as 
         (
             select seqno,category,count(*)over(partition by seqno ) cnt from mytable
         )
         select * from mytable 
         where exists
                        (
                         select * from cte where cnt=1 and trim(Category)='Apple' and 
                         mytable.seqno=cte.seqno
                        );

Comment: And yes thanks once again for your time and help.

Comment: @AsjadAzeez you are most welcome. Sorry, I have misunderstood your need. But hey, you did it.. Cognates. Best wishes.

Comment: You can simplify the final query you need. Please check my Query#1.

Answer (score 0):

I would use window functions to count the number of apples and total rows for a `seq_no` and then use filtering logic:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             count(*) over (partition by seq_no) as cnt,
             sum(case when category = 'Apple' then 1 else 0 end) over (partition by seq_no) as num_apple
      from t
     ) t
where num_apple = 0 or
      (num_apple = cnt and num_apple = 1);
```

The last condition is the one that is ambiguous in the question.  If there are exactly two apples for the `seq_no`, I don't know if it should be returned or not.  If you want such cases, then remove the `num_apple = 1`.

Comment: Awesome, this also works great for me, thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: yes, with a slight tweek of your query i am able to get what i need.

Comment: @AsjadAzeez . . . I don't think the accepted answer works for multiple apples.  That case is covered in this query.